# setting http get request headers in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to send a `GET` request to a third party `api`. I am trying to set two keys but am unable to since this method cannot be resolved `clientHttpRequestFactory`. Reading the doc's of `RestTemplate` I appear to be doing it correctly.

```
@Configuration
public class RequestHeaderConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RequestHeader()));
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class RequestHeader implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {


    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
                                    ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

        HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();
        headers.add("my-key","068a99aksdjfhk9uug67");
        headers.add("subscription-Key","068a999uug67");
        return execution.execute(request, body);

    }
}
```

---

```
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${springfoxSwaggerVersion}")
    compile group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: '1.16.20'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web-services', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.4.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter', version: springBootVersion
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: springBootVersion

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

---

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/api/T1/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    @ApiOperation(value = "This endpoint will get a text from one language to another")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getTranslation() {
        log.info("getTranslation : {} ");

        return new ResponseEntity<String>("TEST TEST TEST", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a `clientHttpRequestFactory` method in the config class. If you don't need one then just remove it from the constructor call

```
@Configuration
public class RequestHeaderConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RequestHeader()));
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```